# rewrite cart url is not working in magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, module

I want to re-write checkout cart url. I had created a module but it is not working. I had created config.xml and Url.php in model but it didn't succeed. my code is: etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ghrix_Newcart>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Ghrix_Newcart>
    </modules>
  <global>
    <rewrite>
      <ghrix_newcart_checkout_cart>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/winkelwagen#]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart#]]></to>
      </ghrix_newcart_checkout_cart>
    </rewrite>
   <models>
      <ghrix_newcart>
        <class>Ghrix_Newcart_Model</class>
      </ghrix_newcart>
      <core>
        <rewrite>
          <url>Ghrix_Newcart_Model_Url</url>
        </rewrite>
      </core>
    </models>
  </global> 
</config>
```

in Model/Url.php

```
<?php
class Ghrix_Newcart_Model_Url extends Mage_Core_Model_Url {
    /**
    * Build url by requested path and parameters
    *
    * @param string|null $routePath
    * @param array|null $routeParams
    * @return string
    */
    public function getUrl($routePath = null, $routeParams = null) {
    if(strstr($routePath,'checkout')){
        //echo $routePath.'--ss--<br />';
    }
        if ( $routePath == 'checkout/cart' ) {          

                $routePath = 'checkout/cart';
            }
            return parent::getUrl($routePath, $routeParams);
        }
} 
?>
```

I had created a function properly but it didn't work for me. I want my checkout/cart url should be checkout/winkelwagen Please suggest what can I do.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Why do you need to send the customer to `checkout/winkelwagen` rather than `checkout/cart`?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach this in a less intrusive way, using Magento’s event observer system. What you could do is redirect all requests to the `checkout/cart` route to your new route `checkout/winkelwagen` with something like this:

**etc/config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
            <observers>
                <redirectCart>
                    <class>Ghrix_Newcart_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>redirectCart</method>
                </redirectCart>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

**Model/Observer.php**

```
public function redirectCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/winkelwagen')->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I had edit my code and its redirecting  but didn't get cart page content.

Comment: my code in config.xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <Ghrix_Newcart>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </Ghrix_Newcart>
 </modules>
  <global>
    <rewrite>
      <ghrix_newcart_checkout_cart>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/winkelwagen#]]></from>
        <to>/checkout/cart</to>
      </ghrix_newcart_checkout_cart>
    </rewrite>
   <models>
      <ghrix_newcart>
        <class>Ghrix_Newcart_Model</class>
      </ghrix_newcart>
      <core>
        <rewrite>
          <url>Ghrix_Newcart_Model_Url</url>
</rewrite>
      </core>
    </models>
  </global> 
</config>

Comment: and Url.php

<?php
class Ghrix_Newcart_Model_Url extends Mage_Core_Model_Url {
 public function getUrl($routePath = null, $routeParams = null) {
  
  //echo $routePath."<br>";
 if(strstr($routePath,'checkout')){
  //echo $routePath.'--ss--<br />';
 }
  if ( $routePath == 'checkout/cart' ) {    
    
    $routePath = 'checkout/winkelwagen';
   }
   return parent::getUrl($routePath, $routeParams);
  }
} 
?>

Comment: suggest me how can I get cart page data on my url.  its rewrite the url to checkout/winkelwagen but didn't get cart page content. how can I get the content ?

Comment: please suggest me what can I do ?

Comment: I want cart page content on checkout/winkelwagen

Comment: I had created newcart.xml in layout

Comment: added frontname and layout in config.xml